# How to compile source that uses dylib path on macOS Sierra from the shell

Tags: g++, macos-sierra, dylib

I'm compiling some source code that requires some dylibs from other project that I have already built. I'm getting

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Whenever I execute

```bash
g++ some_code.cpp -I/usr/local/include -o executable_binary
```

I know that `g++` is not able to find the compiled the dylibs (installed at `/usr/local/include`) since the error also mentions a lot of specific symbols that are part of the dylibs.

I have already tried this:

1. Executing `install_name_tool -id "@/usr/local/lib/requiredlib.dylib" /usr/local/lib/requiredlib.dylib`
2. Adding `-L/usr/local/lib` to the compilation options.
3. Adding all the dylib paths explicitly to the compilation options.
4. Try to add `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` unsuccessfully since Sierra doesn't allow to set that variable for security reasons.

I know that it might possible to add `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` but that requires to disable SIP. I can do it by I do not want to if there is a cleaner way to do this.

P.S.: I am trying to compile the tutorial examples for [Tulip graph library](http://tulip.labri.fr/TulipDrupal/).

The missing symbols are related to the the graph library I have installed. The error message is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tlp::saveGraph(tlp::Graph*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, tlp::PluginProgress*)", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial001-02ee7e.o
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, tlp::Graph const*)", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial001-02ee7e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Whenever I do `ls /usr/local/lib/requiredlib.dylib` the all the compiled libraries from Tulip are there.

`g++ -v` produces:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

After doing `ls /usr/local/include/tulip/` I get the list of `*.h` files of the libraries I intend to use.

Comment: It's not really clear what symbols you're missing, what variant of g++ you're running, etc. And surely your compiled libraries are not installed in `/usr/local/include`

Comment: Edit your question to add these details.

Comment: To get help with a failing linkage you need to post at least the failing
linkage commandline and and its output, *verbatim*. Sketchy reports of
what you have done are too vague to get us beyond guesswork.

Answer (score 6):

In addition, you could also look into the `undefined` option of `ld`

> Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options are: error, warning, suppress, or dynamic_lookup. The default is error.

That you would call like `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` while compiling your binary.

You can also leverage `-lazy-lx` or `-lazy-library path` so that the library is not loaded until the first function in it is called, which might help in some cases.

Then add the rpath flag too, after having changed the name with `install_name_tool` like @macmoonshine showed, but make sure to point to the right path. By default Tulip is installed in the default library folder `/usr/local` but it's recommended in the install guide to do it in a user managed directory.

Something like the following command, for all the libraries required by tulip.

```bash
install_name_tool -change ./build-release/lib/libtulip-core-4.11.dylib '@rpath/libtulip-core-4.11.dylib' tutorial001
```

And also use `-Wl,-rpath,./build-release/lib` while compiling the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `-rpath` to search libraries. After linking your binary you have to modify the search path of the lib, e. g.:

```
g++ some_code.cpp -I/usr/local/include -o binary \
    -L/usr/local/lib -lrequiredlib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/librequiredlib.dylib \
    '@rpath/librequiredlib.dylib' binary
```

The `install_name_tool` command changes the name of the library in the binary such that the lib will be searched in the rpath. If you are unsure about the correct name, use `otool -L binary` to see all libraries linked with your executable.

See man page of `ld` and `install_name_tool` to get more information about rpath. `install_name_tool` can add more rpaths with `-add_rpath` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are bulding x86_64 examples, did you check that your installed .dylibs are also x86_64?

Use `otool` or `file` command to determine that your dylibs are `x86_64`. For example, try something like this `file /usr/local/lib/requiredlib.dylib`. If you don't see this in output:

> requiredlib.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

then your problem is mismatched arch when building libs and when building code that should use these libs.