# Linking C++ code to a DYLIB library in macOS

Tags: c++, linker, g++, macos-sierra, dylib

I was able to [setup BlockSci](https://citp.github.io/BlockSci/setup.html) on [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra) 10.13.6. The setup installed header files in `/usr/local/include` and a `libblocksci.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib`. The C++ code I am trying to compile is:

```
#include "blocksci.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    blocksci::Blockchain chain{"path/config.json"};
    return 0;
};
```

The compile command I am using for `hello.cpp` is:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/blocksci -I/usr/local/include/blocksci/external -o hello hello.cpp
```

However, the symbols for the BlockSci library are not found:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "blocksci::Blockchain::Blockchain(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in hello-942a60.o
  "blocksci::Blockchain::~Blockchain()", referenced from:
      _main in hello-942a60.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong when I try to compile this?

Comment: You told g++ *where* to find libraries, but you didn't tell it *which* libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include needed C library using gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc)

Comment: I tried `g++ -std=c++17 -L/usr/local/lib -llibblocksci.dylib -I/usr/local/include/blocksci -I/usr/local/include/blocksci/external -o hello hello.cpp` but it still does not work, with an error `ld: library not found for -llibblocksci.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

Comment: `-l` option is what you need but it doesn't work the way you think. Please read the manual (perhaps `man gcc`, not sure how to do this on your system but you can find it online). Yes it's long, but it's searchable. I could quote the relevant section but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789619/how-to-compile-source-that-uses-dylib-path-on-macos-sierra-from-the-shell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053085/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libmwmclmcrrt-8-4-dylib) that were helpful. It finally compiled with:

```
g++ hello.cpp -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include/blocksci/external -o hello -L/usr/local/lib -lblocksci -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
```

However, now I get a runtime error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error
Abort trap: 6
```

Back to the drawing board, but it compiled for now.